I want to embed a unity game into my own html website
I created my own website and I want to embed a game in it. My problems are that the audio is playing twice and the iframe adds something beneath the game.
I built the game and got its html format. I got the following code:

What should I do to make it not double the audio and place something beneath. (The way it's displayedI want it to have no scrollbar and just be the game's size and not play the audio twice)

Please write your code correctly. There is no your code.
